# python read from text file line by line

Tags: python, printing, split, anaconda, filereader

I want my code to read from a text file and fill the data into a list.

[image: the Text file]

The code that I want to reach:

```
dataset = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
           ['b', 'c'],
           ['a', 'b', 'c'],
           ['d'],
           ['b', 'c']]
```

I already tried this code:

```
dataset = open(filename).read().split('\n')
for items in dataset:
        print(items)
```

[image: result from printing the list]

I got the List included white spaces, so how I can solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: You have to partition your input twice: once to get the individual lines of input; a second time to `split` each line into its individual letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script loads the file into `dataset` list:

```
dataset = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f_in:
    for items in f_in:
        dataset.append(items.split())

print(dataset)
```

Prints:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can read line by line and then split each line by words:

```
dataset = []
with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp.lines():
        dataset.append(line.split())
```